# Diagnosing web server port 80

Tags: apache-2.4, windows-server-2012, port, port-80

Got Windows Server 2012 installation for work, by a network admin(first time around dealing with a server, or setting up apache from scratch etc).

Setup Apache to get things rolling, so I can at least connect to the server and display a html page through port 80. If I launch apache, and use netstat from the actual server(via rdp), I can deduct that Apache is listening to connections on port 80.

However, if I use telnet to check from an external source, it says connection failed on port 80, and online port checkers deduct that the port is closed(set up proper firewall permissions as well, also have tried it with the firewall turned off, doesn't make a difference).I can't access the web page.

My question is, if port 80 is listening on the local server side, but can't be reached by any type of port checking, does that mean it's not setup properly on the hardware side of things? How could I further diagnose this?

[netstat results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B0W7.png)

Comment: To start, I would try to telnet localhost 80

Comment: Ye, I can connect to localhost port 80 fine in the server.

Comment: When you say "external source" do you mean from same network or different network? If from same network it works fine and from external network id doesn't, you will need to check on your network design

Comment: So i just checked, it connects fine from the server itself, and if I use telnet serverip 80 from a computer within the same network. If I try to connect from a computer outside of the network, it can't connect.

Comment: So further analysis on your network must be done; network devices involved, NAT/Port forwarding, traceroutes...

Comment: How are you calling your webserver? IP or Name? Has this been configured in Apache [Binding to Addresses and Ports](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html)

Answer (score 0):

Disable firewall or add firewall rule for 80\TCP port like there: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/managing-the-windows-server-2012-firewall/

Comment: "set up proper firewall permissions as well, also have tried it with the firewall turned off, doesn't make a difference"

Comment: Does Apache listening on all interfaces? `netstat -anb | findstr ":80"`

Comment: It isn't powershell. Run from elevated prompt and check that apache process listen on port 80. If `netstat -anb | findstr ":80"` return nothing try `netstat -anb`

Comment: my bad, just did it, i put up the netstat results in my original question.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see the screenshots - imgur blocked. Perhaps it helps someone else.